# Print functionality in Telidos platform(using GWT)

Tags: gwt

we have website which is developed in Telidos platform which is using GWT in side it. but 
In that website we need print functionality to be included. When the user clicks on print button, then the application should print the search criteria and the content from that page. I don't know how to implement it. I searched in all the places where i couldn't find any solution.

Please help me on this if anybody have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Jothi, In GWT we have everything in a GWT widget. It may be a RootPanel. VerticalPanel, SplitPanel ans so on. So try this,

For eg. If you to print a CellTable which is added in a VerticalPanel,

```
VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
vPanel.add(cellTable);
```

Then print it by

```
String printText = vPanel.asWidget().getElement().getInnerHTML();
printMethod(printText);
```

And have the following method,

```
public static native void printMethod(String html) /*-{
var frame = $doc.getElementById('printing');
if (!frame) {
$wnd.alert("Error: Can't find printing frame.");
return;
}
frame = frame.contentWindow;
var doc = frame.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(html);
doc.close();
frame.focus();
frame.print();
}-*/;
```

where 'printing' is the iframe id.

```
<iframe id="printing" style="width:0;height:0;border:0">
</iframe>
```

This should be added in your *.ui.xml for the particular widget like

```
<g:Verticalpanel><iframe id="printing" style="width:0;height:0;border:0">
</iframe></g:Verticalpanel>
```